# Powerline with Vim with ImportError: can't find appropriate configuration

Tags: python, vim, powerline

I've been trying to get [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) working for awhile and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I often use vim inside of tmux, but the error is the same inside of tmux and out.

This is the error I get when I invoke vim:

```
$ vim
Error detected while processing /Users/jlconlin/.vim/powerline.vim:
line    4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named powerline.vim
line    5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'powerline_setup' is not defined
line    6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'powerline_setup' is not defined
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My guess is that Vim doesn't know where to look for the python packages/modules, but I can't figure out how to tell Vim what to do. I've searched far and wide through Google (including stackexchange) and haven't found a solution.

In my `.vimrc` file I have:

```
set rtp+=$POWERLINE_ROOT/powerline/bindings/vim
let g:pymcd_powerline="py3"

python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python powerline_setup()
python del powerline_setup
```

`POWERLINE_ROOT` is set with the command

```
POWERLINE_ROOT=$(pip show powerline-status | sed -n 's/Location: \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

I have installed Python3 with the anaconda distribution and I've installed powerline with pip:

```
$ pip show po werline-status
Name: powerline-status
Version: 2.7
Summary: The ultimate statusline/prompt utility.
Home-page: https://github.com/powerline/powerline
Author: Kim Silkebaekken
Author-email: kim.silkebaekken+vim@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Users/jlconlin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by
```

I use MacVim—which has both python and python3 support—and use the internal version for my terminal vim:

```
$ which vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/vim

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct 30 2019 11:57:56)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-2234
Compiled by travis@Traviss-Mac.local
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
+balloon_eval_term +fullscreen        +num64             +textprop
+browse            -gettext           +odbeditor         +timers
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +title
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +toolbar
+channel           +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +transparency
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +python/dyn        +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             +xim
+dnd               +mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework AppKit   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE
```

Comment: If your terminal vim is using the internal Python version, why would you expect it to detect packages installed to the Anaconda setup?

Comment: Anyway, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557020/execute-different-version-of-python-in-vimrc-file help? (You say "I've searched far and wide through Google (including stackexchange)"; I put `vim set python version` into DuckDuckGo and that was the 6th result for me.)

Comment: I didn’t know what python Vim would use. I assumed it would use the first one found in the PATH variable. I had tried to find out which one, but couldn’t figure it out. I’ll check the link you specified to see if it helps